# What is the best way to store a non-rectangular array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I would like to store a non-rectangular array in Python. The array has millions of elements and I will be applying a function to each element in the array, so I am concerned about performance. What data structure should I use? Should I use a Python list or a numpy array of type `object`? Is there another data structure that would work even better?

Comment: What type are these millions of elements?

Comment: They are one-dimensional arrays of varying length containing integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dictionary data structure to store everything. If you have ample memory, dictionaries is a good option. The hashing process makes them faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use scipy [sparse matrices](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/03/sparse-matrices-in-python-with-scipy/).
UPD. Some elaboration goes below.

I assume that "non-rectangular" implies there will be empty elements in plain 2D array. Having millions of elements will make these 'holes' tax on memory usage. Sparse matrix provide a way to have familiar array interface and occupy only necessary amount of memory.
Though if array-ish indexing is not required, dictionary is pretty fine storage to use.

Comment: It will be good if you could add an explanation of it's benefit. Links may dead in the future.